# Java: Alternating Boolean values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Assume that the array foo consists of alternating value, index at 0 = true, 1 = false, 2 = true, etc.
Ex:

```
for (int index = 0; index < foo.length; index++)
```

I'm trying to find a way to complete this code by only using one statement. So far the only idea I have is:

```
foo[index] = !index--; // I want it to check the last Boolean of index, and reverse it
```

This is of course bad code and doesn't exist, but is there a way to alternate and have it look like something like this:

```
foo[index] = (code that goes in here);
```

Comment: *Assume that the array foo consists of alternating value*. Then what are you trying to do?

Comment: If they are alternating, couldn't you just check the value of what *would* be the index and know what the value should be?

Answer (score 4):

Since boolean arrays are initially all false.

```
boolean [] foo = new boolean[100];
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i+=2)
    foo[i] = true;
```

Comment: +1 Elegant solution. This avoids redundant assignments of `false` values and cuts the amount of iterations by half.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bit operations or modulo division:

```
foo[index] = (index & 1) == 0;
```

or

```
foo[index] = (index % 2) == 0;
```

Comment: This wasn't what I thought of going about this way, but it definitely makes sense! Thank you, I didn't know that you could do it this way! Definitely opened me to new ideas of coding!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is iterate with a loop up to some maximum value and then use the modulus to determine the boolean value:

```
boolean array = new boolean[foo.length];
for (int index = 0; index < foo.length; index++) {
    array[i] = index % 2 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
Foo[index] = (index%2==0)
```

Answer (score -1):

`for (int index = 0; index < foo.length; index++)
    foo[index]=!foo[index];`
is optimized but, If you want complex, you can try this too.

`for (int index = foo.length-1; index >0; index--)
    foo[index]=foo[(index+1)%2];foo[index]=!foo[index];`

Comment: I am extremely sorry @TobiasBrösamle , I did blunder .... Thanks for pointing this out. Actually I got it another way, Like, I have one boolean array having `true false true false .....` and need to just find out `!` of that .... really .... embarrassed .... And the solution on the comment was a crime ... so deleted that ....